# getJSON not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am trying to fetch some data from my localhost url (`/data`) to another localhost url (`/`) but I'm not getting any data

```
...var x = (new Date()).getTime(), 
        y = 2.0;
        $.getJSON('/data', {}, function(data){
             value = data.tem_min;
        })
        series.addPoint([x, value], true, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getJSON` is an async function so when you execute:

```
series.addPoint([x, value], true, true);
```

`value` is null because the function you passed to `getJSON` is not being executed until the http request is done.

So you just need to use the value after it's set:

```
$.getJSON('/data', {}, function(data){
    value = data.tem_min;
    series.addPoint([x, value], true, true);
})
```